# passing array values to a subreport

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I am new to crystal report and I need a help.
I have a report having two groups,project id and work_item. And I placed 3 sub reports material,labor and equipment reports in the work item group. They pass a value to the main report that is used for further calculation which is specific for a work item..

Since it's a work item specific,I placed the final result in the work item group footer.

I placed another sub report called bill of quantities in the work item group footer that needs the final value. It's also work item specific The value being passed is fine but I am having issues with the format.

After displaying the detail of one work item,the sub reports detail follows it which I didn't want that to be displayed. I tried placing the sub report in the project id group footer. The format I need is good but the value being passed is the same for all work items in the sub report.

The thing I need is after displaying all the details of the main report then displays the sub report detail.

Is there a way to store those final values of the work items in an array and pass them to the sub report.[image: sample output]

Answer (score 0):

Well, Yes you can store details in an array, when you are loading the main report, loop thorugh the data of the main report :

```
shared stringvar array items;
for int i:=1 to limit(count of project_id)
do
(
whileprintingrecords;
items[i]:= //add values, you can make a logic, this is just the demo
);
items;
```

Then simply place this formula in a section suppressed, just above the subreport, so that this can be passed with values in the subreport.

Declare a formula, and use the shared values:

```
shared stringvar array items;
numbervar count_i:=//get the count of items and add array values into another formula/field.

//place that field in subreport, this may require some brainstorming from your end, but this is the way in general.
```